# Routing issues with pgrouting

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

I was using the pgrouting plugin to display the shortestpath. I used the plugin as suggested by underdark to display the shortest path in qgis.

My source node is 283 and my target node is 172. When I used the pgrouting plugin to give me the shortest path I got one as attached in the screenshot.

[image]

However, when I queried the database of the graph which was generated by the tool osm2po. I found only one edge which was connected to node 283.

The result of the query is given in the figure below
[image]

My question is if you look at the results of the query, the edge is from node 279-283 and is one way as well with 283 being the target. Now since I used qgis to show the shortest path from 283-172. There is no starting from 283 as source. So my assumption was it shouldn't have shown any path. So I was wondering if there are some issues with the pgrouting plugin.

How come it gave me the shortest path when there is no edge with 283 as source? As I have explained there is only one edge connected to 283, but 283 is target and also the edge is one way from source to target.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that if only one way(but high reverse_cost value(1000000)) exists,
shortest path(dijkstra) function use the way although it has high reverse cost.

Could you execute following query on phppgadmin for confirmation?.

```
SELECT route.vertex_id, route.cost AS route_cost, m_2po_4pgr.* 
FROM m_2po_4pgr 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM shortest_path(
 'SELECT id AS id, source::int4 AS source, target::int4 AS target, 
  cost::float8 AS cost ,reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost 
  FROM m_2po_4pgr ', 283,172, True, True)) AS route 
ON m_2po_4pgr.id= route.edge_id
```

Comment: +1 That's the most likely explanation. One solution would be to check if the total route costs are over 1000000. Then the route should be discarded.

Comment: Yeah I checked the total cost as well and it is above 1000000. So isn't it a bug in pgrouting? I mean it should have shown something like route not found or not connected, something liek that

Comment: If you want to exclude those high cost value, update reverse_cost to negative value(like "-1"). (see http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/dijkstra.html). But, in windows, server process closed unexpectedly. And it seems that old bug has not been fixed. (http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/pgrouting-users/2010-May/000304.html). So currently it may be better to discard high cost value.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an ambiguity issue with [has_reverse_cost] and [directed] because a directed graph does not need a reverse_cost attribute.