# pgRouting：routing problems using reverse_cost

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, postgis-1.5

I saw this post：[Routing issues with pgrouting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29445/routing-issues-with-pgrouting/29448#29448), and try the ability of reverse_cost.

As the result of this post, if there is only one way to go from one node to another, even though the reverse_cost is very huge, pgRouting can still give the result the same as the one that I do not use reverse_cost(but this time the cost is drastically huge), but apparently it's unreasonable.

Then I try to set the reverse_cost to **negative value**, unfortunately under Win7 the error occurs：

[image]

Can someway I can do to solve this problem？

Or under this condition can pgRouting return one acceptable and operable result like "route not found" or "route not connected"？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about pgRouting. There are lots of other things you should check.

- Check if your LAN cable is plugged or WiFi is connected.
- Check if your PostgreSQL server is working properly.
- Check if your connection host/port to PostgreSQL is set correctly.
- Check if your machine or PostgreSQL server is ignoring port 5432.